# User-agent error with web scraping python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, user-agent

It is my first time using web scraping. When I am using `page = requests.get(URL)` it works perfectly fine but when I am adding

```
headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
```

I am getting an error

```
    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

What's wrong with that? Should I resign with headers?

Comment: print page.content and check what response  it is having

Comment: That's strange cause it's different with and without headers, with headers it's giving something like that [link](https://pastebin.com/WN2s1n30) (it's only some part of the output)

Comment: @jakub0301 Can you share the URL? If I look at your link, I don't see any tags with `id=productTitle`

Comment: ```import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JP9QJ15/ref=dp_cerb_1'

headers = {"User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
print(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the page contains non valid HTML and therefore BeatifulSoup is not able to find your element.

Try to prettify the HTML first:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07JP9QJ15/ref=dp_cerb_1'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_2) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.4 Safari/605.1.15'}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

pretty = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser').prettify()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pretty,'html.parser')
print(soup.find(id='productTitle').get_text())
```

Which returns:

Dell UltraSharp U2719D - LED Monitor - 27"